# HTTP Batch Get from multiple APIs and save to struct

Tags: go

I have the following function that I use to get a URL and return the data to an interface (e.g. struct/int/whatever):

```
var httpClient = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}

func getURLToTarget(url string, target interface{}) error {
    req, err := httpClient.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer req.Body.Close()
    return json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(target)
}
```

then I have several functions that look like this:

```
func GetCustomerByID(APIKey, cusID string) {
  cus := new(Customer)
  getURLToTarget(fmt.Sprintf("http://someurl.com/%s/customerbyid/:%s", APIKey, cusID), &cus)
}
```

which in this case will save the json response into a struct like this:

```
type Customer struct {
  Name string
  Email string
  Address string
}
```

Now my question is, how can I make all these http requests perform simultaneously when I run:

```
func main() {
  apikey := "some api key"
  GetCustomerByID(apikey, "43279843")
  GetCustomerDiscounts(apikey, "43279843")
  GetProductByID(apikey, "32124")
}
```

I am pretty sure I need to use channels but I can't figure out how.. any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Well, Go has a nice keyword for running things concurrently, it's called `go`. I'd recommend working through the Tour of Go which explains this stuff much better than any SO answer could do.

Comment: assuming you refer to tour.golang.org/concurrency then I think it's the first place anyone (including myself) go to.. but in my case that (as well as the online articles I've read wasn't enough)

Comment: and assuming you meant simply adding 'go' in front of the function calls, then I'm 99% sure it doesn't result in batch pull so it's still making X requests (in this case 3) instead of doing it with 1 request

Comment: Uuum, what about: 1. fetch 2. store `req.Body` 3. run `json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(target)` for each struct you want on the stored body

Comment: I guess I don't understand because I thought that's what I do with getURLToTarget?

Comment: @fisker in your question you asked `how can I make all these http requests perform simultaneously when I run: ...`, @Volker's comment is spot on, prefix your function call with the `go` keyword and those 3 functions will be executed simultaneously. From your comments though, you seem to want to make only **1** HTTP request instead of **3**, which is not possible if the api to which you are making those requests doesn't provide an endpoint for batch resources.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense.. guess I was being stupid again.. thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this and it's based on what you need to happen.

The basic one is to use goroutines and wg.WaitGroup to do http call in parallel/concurrent and wait for all of it to finish before exiting the program. For example:

```
func main() {
  apikey := "some api key"

  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  wg.Add(3)

  go func() {
    GetCustomerByID(apikey, "43279843")
    wg.Done()
  }()

  go func() {
    GetCustomerDiscounts(apikey, "43279843")
    wg.Done()
  }()

  go func() {
    GetProductByID(apikey, "32124")
    wg.Done()
  }()

  wg.Wait()
}
```

Another approach is to use go channel if you want to inspect the result of each http call. For example:

```
func GetCustomerByID(APIKey, cusID string) Customer {
  cus := new(Customer)
  getURLToTarget(fmt.Sprintf("http://someurl.com/%s/customerbyid/:%s", APIKey, cusID), &cus)
  return cus
}

func main() {
  apikey := "some api key"

  c := make(chan Customer, 3)

  go func() {
    cus := GetCustomerByID(apikey, "43279843")
    c <- cus
  }()

  go func() {
    cus := GetCustomerDiscounts(apikey, "43279843")
    c <- cus
  }()

  go func() {
    cus := GetProductByID(apikey, "32124")
    c <- cus
  }()

  // Print the result
  var i int
  for cus := range c {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", cus)
    i++

    if i == 3 {
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid but I think this way will still send 3 requests instead of 1? I think there's a concept related to batching http requests so that instead of sending X separate requests (which happens in parallel with your answer), then you just send 1 request to do it all?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't get your requirement, here you want to have just 1 http call for 3 different http requests?

Comment: Yeah but @mkopriva says it's not possible (at least not the way I thought it was) so I guess your answer achieves the best possible outcome given the circumstances :)